# Parent element height not inherited

Tags: html, css, height

I've got a misbehaving `div` that doesn't want to inherit its parent height. The one with `100%` has 0 height:

```
<div>
  <div style="border: 1px red solid; display: table-cell; width: 20px;">
    <div style="height: 100%; border: 1px green solid;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="border: 1px blue solid; display: table-cell;">a</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/muzq7g7b/1/

Its parent gets its sibling's (the one with letter `a`) height, that's good. But why the child doesn't receive it is a mystery to me.

Comment: "The one with 100% has 0 height", does that mean the value 100% is not working..?

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw exactly, 100% resolves into 0 height! when I omit height it is 0 too :)

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw fiddle added

Comment: add `height: 100%` to the parent table cell. https://jsfiddle.net/muzq7g7b/2/

Comment: @MichaelCoker sorry but your fiddle still has green single height element, which means the child element height is zero

Comment: @OlegMikheev ah are you using firefox? My fiddle works fine in chrome. in FF looks like you need to also add a row and add the height to the row https://jsfiddle.net/muzq7g7b/3/

Comment: @MichaelCoker oh wow, that worked! please add as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome, you need to add `height: 100%;` to the parent table cell

```html
<div>
  <div style="border: 1px red solid; display: table-cell; height: 100%; width: 20px;">
    <div style="height: 100%; border: 1px green solid;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="border: 1px blue solid; display: table-cell;">a</div>
</div>
```

In Firefox, you need to add a parent `table-row` and add `height: 100%;` to it

```html
<div style="display:table-row; height: 100%;">
  <div style="border: 1px red solid; display: table-cell; height: 100%; width: 20px;">
    <div style="height: 100%; border: 1px green solid;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="border: 1px blue solid; display: table-cell;">a</div>
</div>
```

And in internet explorer, you need to replicate a full table and add `height: 100%` to each parent.

```html
<div style="display: table; height: 100%">
  <div style="display:table-row; height: 100%;">
    <div style="border: 1px red solid; display: table-cell; height: 100%; width: 20px;">
      <div style="height: 100%; border: 1px green solid;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px blue solid; display: table-cell;">a</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I remember I answered a question a while ago by the same approach, but couldn't make it work in IE, can you confirm if that works? I don't have IE to test at the moment.

Comment: @Pangloss good call. I have an edge VM. Just checked... wait for it... doesn't work! Hah. but it's a relatively easy fix and updated my answer. http://i.imgur.com/z8IgJzj.png

Comment: Just had a chance to test it on IE, in fact it's not working on IE 11 and 10 etc, I guess there is some magic about Edge.

Comment: @Pangloss well poop, thanks for checking. All I have is the edge VM at the moment. I'll try and get the 10/11 VM's tomorrow and see if I can find a workaround.